# Update UIScrollView's contents during pan gesture

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer, setneedsdisplay

I have a timed simulation running in a custom `UIView` (where I'm doing 2D painting in `drawRect`) that I've now embedded in a `UIScrollView`. To my disappointment, the timer-generated calls to `setNeedsDisplay()` of the custom view are *not* resulting in actual display refreshes *during* a long scroll (panning gesture over several seconds, in which case several simulation frames are lost). Instead the last contents of the custom view are frozen during the gesture then update immediately to the latest upon the end of the gesture.

Is there a way to force the contents of a UIScrollView to redraw during zooms, pinches, and pans? Various blind wall-dart attempts at "forcing something" during the UIScrollView's delegate methods have failed.

Comment: I assume you're using `NSTimer` because you said “the timer-generated calls”. If you're not using `NSTimer`, post a comment and I'll reopen.

Comment: Thank you, I mistakenly assumed that the timer was running.